# Cómo obtengo el nombre de un archivo dado un String como path con java?

Tags: java, string

Tengo una cadena:

```
String path = "CarpetaTop/CarpetaMid/CarpetaBot/NombreArchivo.jpg";
```

Así me la regresa lo que consulto pero necesito separar el string de carpetas de las del archivo. Algo como obtener:

```
String carpetas = "CarpetaTop/CarpetaMid/CarpetaBot/";
String nombreArchivo = "NombreArchivo.jpg";
```

Cómo hago esto o qué método de java me ayuda a hacer esto?

Comment: Hola User. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Que probaste? Te sugiero usar `split("/")`  y quedarte el ultimo elemento del array, o usar `substring + lastIndexOf` o incluso `regex` si te atreves con ellas ... prueba y si tienes problemas concretos, pregunta aqui  siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo ^^

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tengo pocas opciones, me hubiera gustado hacerlo con split pero lo que uso no tiene la herramienta nativa para hacer un split, pero sí tiene substring, ahorita investigo un poco cómo hacerlo con substring y si tengo problemas vuelvo

Comment: Para hacerlo con substring necesito saber la posición exacta de dónde comienza el nombre del archivo... ese path puede variar muchísimo, entonces substring no me sirve :C

Comment: por eso sugiero usarlo junto con `lastindexOf` y usar el '/'

Comment: Veo el substring en java con uno o dos parámetros disponibles, ambos son enteros (index), existe un método de substring que acepte index y string? :O

Comment: Usar lastIndexOf para saber el index del ultimo diagonal... ya hahaha gracias xD

Answer (score -1):

Metodo split

```
String carpetas = "CarpetaTop/CarpetaMid/CarpetaBot/NombreArchivo.jpg";;
String[] partes = carpetas.split("/");
String parte1 = partes[0]; // CarpetaTop
String parte2 = partes[1]; // CarpetaMid
String parte3 = partes[2]; // CarpetaBot
String parte4 = partes[3]; // NombreArchivo.jpg
```

El nombre del archivo queda en el indice partes.length-1

Comment: Si lees los comentarios, el usuario dice que no puede usar split. De todas maneras es mejor esperar a que el autor edite la pregunta para explicar qué intentó y qué fallo para huddle en eso y no en hacerle la tarea. Un saludo